# ImportError: No module named **** appears when running from cmd prompt for any module

Tags: python, numpy

First noticed that when running scripts via command prompt I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.
```

Later changed so that `numpy` was imported on a lower line and the error became

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot.
```

Code is at the bottom.

I'm using `Windows 10` and I only have `python 3.7.0` installed and have not had another version on this computer. I am not using a virtual environment.
The `numpy` version `1.15`.

I have been running scripts from the `cmd` prompt by navigating to the folder that the script resides in and calling that file, so that it appears:

```
C:\PythonPrograms\ProjectName>main.py
```

Installed packages with `pip3 install <packagename>`. Modules appears in the python directory under `lib/site-packages`. Running scripts from `IDLE` has no issue, only through command prompt.

Why is this occuring and how do I fix it?

```
#Examples of dataframe operations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
rs = np.random.randn(200)
xs = [0]

for r in rs:
    xs.append(xs[-1]*0.9 + r)

df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns = ["data"])

df['min'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) > df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) > df.data)]
df['max'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) < df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) < df.data)]

plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c = 'r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c = 'g')
df.data.plot()
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual enviornment? (folder called venv or something similar in same folder as the script). If so you need to install numpy for that enviornment instead of the global one. And please post your code how you are importing it in the script and running the script from the command line.

Comment: Can you please show, what exactly you are doing, and how are you running your code through the terminal?

Comment: Suggest to use `Anaconda` to manage Python packages in Windows.